# How to add a column in a sql query with selection of the result

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a sql statment like this:

```
SELECT  a.link_id, a.Speed_Limit_1, a.Speed_Limit_2, a.speed_limit_source, g.autos, g.trucks, g.motorcycles, 'vehicleType' as vehicleType

FROM  g, f, d, a

WHERE  f.access_id = g.access_id
AND d.condition_id = f.condition_id
AND g.access_id = a.access_id
```

result:

link_id......autos...trucks...motorcycles.........**vehicleTypes**

---

1..........|.......Y....|....Y......|.....N.................|.............?

2..........|.......Y....|....Y......|.....Y.................|.............?

3..........|.......Y....|....Y......|.....N.................|.............?

4..........|.......Y....|....N......|.....Y.................|.............?

I will add the column "vehicleTypes. Inside this column should be:

0 if autos, trucks and motorcycles are allowed (e.g. row 2)

1 if only cars are allowed

2 if only trucks are allowed

3 if only motorcycles are allowed

How can I do this?

Comment: You are selecting from multiple tables? It's better to use JOINS

Comment: Also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using postgreSQL

Comment: @Phil3992, those are joins, old style, implicit ones.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. 
I added an ELSE -1 to indicate where it didnt match any of the criteria.

```
SELECT  
    a.link_id, 
    a.Speed_Limit_1, 
    a.Speed_Limit_2, 
    a.speed_limit_source, 
    g.autos, g.trucks, 
    g.motorcycles, 

    CASE 
        WHEN g.autos = 'Y' AND g.trucks = 'Y' AND g.motorcycles = 'Y' THEN 0
        WHEN g.autos = 'Y' AND g.trucks = 'N' AND g.motorcycles = 'N' THEN 1
        WHEN g.autos = 'N' AND g.trucks = 'Y' AND g.motorcycles = 'N' THEN 2
        WHEN g.autos = 'N' AND g.trucks = 'N' AND g.motorcycles = 'Y' THEN 3
        ELSE -1
    END as vehicleTypes

FROM  g, f, d, a

WHERE  f.access_id = g.access_id
AND d.condition_id = f.condition_id
AND g.access_id = a.access_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CASE WHEN` block

for example in Oracle:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php